# In Android how to call a popup window when a button in another custom popup window is clicked

Tags: android, popupwindow

On clicking a button in my main screen, I have a dialog box opening.
On clicking a button in the dialog box, a pop-up screen opens.The following is the code. This part works fine.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.FullHeightDialog);

// dialog box layout is layout.xml
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout);

//layout of pop-up window is howtoplay.xml
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.howtoplay, null, false);
final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(popupView,400,440, true);


//On clicking button in dialog,popup opens
Button howto = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rules);
howto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pw.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.howtoplay, null, false));
            pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            pw.update(0,0,wth*8,ht*10);

            Button close = (Button)pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.done);
            close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pw.dismiss();

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

I want to open a pop-up screen(playvideo.xml) when a button in the howtoplay pop-up screen is clicked. The following is the code I've written in the onclicklistener method of the button.

```
public void howtoplayvideo(View v){
    System.out.println("------clicked-------");
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playvodeo, null, false);
    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(popupView,400,440, true);
    pw.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.playvideo, null, false));
    pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    pw.update(0,0,wth*8,ht*10);
}
```

"clicked" is getting printed, but then am getting an exception

```
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@453afa80 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late but the reason why your code is not working is because the you are saying:

> pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

The v you have passed in is the view for the howto button and not for your layout view that you want the popupwindow to show on  top of.